# Test fails when I include an array reference in regex (array with index in regex) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I am doing a challenge on freeCodeCamp. I am passed an array with 2 strings, the instructions are to test to see if the letters in the second string are in the first string.

Here's what I have:

`return /[arr\[1\]]/gi.test(arr[0]);`

This passes all the tests except where it tries to match with a capital letter.

`mutation(["hello", "Hello"]) should return true.`

It's the only test that fails, I have tested my regex on regexr.com with:

`/[Hello]/gi` and it matches with 'hello'.

Yes, there are other ways to do it, but why does it fail when I pass the string into the regex from the array?

EDIT: https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-algorithm-scripting/mutations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your code passes the test for `["Mary", "Army"]` shows that the problem is not one of case sensitivity. The only reason your code passes any of the tests is that `/[arr\[1\]]/` looks for matches against the set of characters `ar1[]` which coincidentally happens to correctly match 8 of the 9 tests. Anyway the other - perhaps biggest - issue is that you are not testing **all** of the characters in `arr[1]` against `arr[0]`; if you run @Emeeus's answer it returns false positives for many of the tests. So, to test all of the characters in `arr[1]` against `arr[0]` you need something like this:

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  return arr[1].split('').reduce((t, c) => t && new RegExp(c, 'i').test(arr[0]), true);
}

let tests = [
  ['hello', 'hey'],
  ["hello", "Hello"],
  ["zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba", "qrstu"],
  ["Mary", "Army"],
  ["Mary", "Aarmy"],
  ["Alien", "line"],
  ["floor", "for"],
  ["hello", "neo"],
  ["voodoo", "no"]
];

tests.map(arr => console.log(arr[0] + ", " + arr[1] + " => " + (mutation(arr) ? 'match' : 'no match')));
```

Comment: Hi @Nick, thanks for taking the time to answer this fully. I still don't understand that, even when I change all the arr[1] to lowercase, the test still fails. If it was 'coincidentally' then surely it would match 'hello' with 'hello' using my original implementation.

Comment: It didn't match because "hello" doesn't contain any of the characters a,r,1,[ or ]. If you look at the tests that passed, the ones which matched all contain an a or an r (zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba, Mary, Alien) and the ones that didn't match (hello, voodoo) didn't. This just happened (with the exception of `['hello', 'Hello']` to match the expected result of the test.

Comment: Ah! Wow, thanks for catching that. Time to refactor!

Answer (score 2):

keep in mind that with this: `return /[arr\[1\]]/gi.test(arr[0])` you are evaluating exactly this string `"arr[1]"`. [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp/test) is a method of RegExp, then to add variables in a regex, or build the regex as string,  you should use the [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). Like the example below.

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility) for browser compatibility of flags.

```js
function mutation(str){

    var r = new RegExp(str[0].toLowerCase(), "gi")
    return r.test(str[1].toLowerCase());

}


console.log(mutation(["hello", "Hello"]))
```

Comment: but I have the case-insensitive flag in my expression too?

Comment: Thanks,  flags is a pretty universal standard, though.

Comment: I think, at least in this case, it's not because of case sensitivity. The problem might be that you can't use variables in a regex literal. https://www.hacksparrow.com/javascript-use-variables-with-regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a special syntax for Regular Expressions. Those two lines are essentially the same:

```
return /[arr\[1\]]/gi.test(arr[0]);
return new RegExp('[arr\\[1\\]]', 'gi').test(arr[0]);
```

but what you probably want is this:

```
new RegExp('['+arr[1]+']', 'gi').test(arr[0]);
```

However, you should be careful since this approach does not work if it contains special characters such as '[' or ']'.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a javascript variable in a regular expression, you should construct a new [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) object. Taken from your question, it should look like this

```
return new RegExp(arr[1], "gi").test(arr[0]);
```

As one hint on freeCodeCamp.org says, you can solve the problem easier if you transform the strings into arrays, using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). No need for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
return /[arr\[1\]]/gi.test(arr[0]);
```

you can do:

```
return new RegEx(arr[1], gi);
```

Your code uses a character match (`[ ]`), not a string match, so it will match anything, that has those characters directly (That's why uppercase and lowercase differs, although you have specified 'i').

The new expression directly uses the string to match, not just the characters.